# What is this box on my HVAC duct?

Tags: hvac

I took down my dropped ceiling to replace w Sheetrock and found this box attached to the duct. It makes a humming/buzzing noise and clicks on and off when the furnace goes on/off.

- What is this box and why does it buzz/make noise?
- Can it be quieted?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a control box to open/close a flap/damper.  If you can remove it from the duct and place rubber/foam stripes under the mounting it might quiet it some what.  Looks it is mounted using metal screws, so should be easy.

Comment: That appears to be a motorized damper which opens when the fan kicks on to allow air to flow and closes when the fan turns off to prevent (or at least minimize) air flow. Does it buzz _constantly_ or just when the furnace is turning on/shutting down?

Comment: @FreeMan - More likely it's tied to a thermostat somewhere.

Comment: Please add a picture of the mechanism that's cut off at the left edge of this picture. Also, a close up of the writing on the duct just under that hole that the copper pipe/rod runs through would be helpful so we can read what it says.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that clicking the up vote button for any and all answers that help you, and clicking the check mark for the answer that helps you the _most_ are considered the proper way to close out a question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a motor mounted to the duct work to control a damper that will open or close to allow more or less air to flow through the duct. This is *likely* to control temperature in a "zone" in your house.

The motor rotates the silver linkage on the right around the right hand green line, translating that motion through the bar (yellow highlight), causing the bar on the left (green highlight) to also rotate, moving the damper within the duct.

[image: highlighted version of OPs original picture]

To confirm this, have someone adjust the heat up high while you're watching this, and you should see it move. Have them turn the heat back down low and you'll see it move again.

As noted in a comment, the clicking noises are relays opening/closing to actuate the motor. The buzzing/humming sound would be the motor itself running.

There's probably not much you can do to quiet the relay clicks, but if the buzz really bothers you, you can probably remove the box from the duct then put some sort of foam rubber between the box and the duct and remount it. This should help isolate the vibration of the motor from the duct which will make it quieter, since the duct is acting like a guitar body to amplify the vibrations.

It's also possible, especially if you're noticing buzzing now that you didn't in the past, that the mechanism has jammed or that the motor is failing and what you're hearing is the motor struggling to turn against the failure point. If that's the case, it might be time to replace this damper controller. If it appears that you're heading down this path, find the builder's plate on the motor housing which should indicate the brand/model number as well as all the specs about it so you can find a replacement. It looks like this plate is on the right hand side where all the wires connect.

Comment: Re-riveting the mounting tabs to the top of the box and then attaching the box to the ceiling (with appropriate shims to keep it in the same location) could help cut the noise by uncoupling it from the ducting.

Comment: Wow. Thank you SO MUCH for this detailed explanation. When they replaced the furnace they said I i only have 1 zone. The part of the rod that is cutoff in the pic actually goes through to a closet where there are 2 aluminum boxes which I was told ar useless. The buzzing is constant and it is very annoying. And you are right, it clicks on and off when the thermostat triggers. I will try and remove and see if I can add something between it to minimize some of the noise.